# Waiting for another process

Tags: c

I know that there's a lot of answers concerning the main problem , but I still can't find a solution .
My problem is I have two childs and I want the first one to wait for the second one .
Here I tried to do a little approach of my problem .
**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>

void affiche(int *tab)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%i-%i-%i-%i-%i\n",tab[0],tab[1],tab[2],tab[3],tab[4]);
}
int main()
{
pid_t pid,pid2;
pid_t pid_child;

int buffer1[30]={1,1,1,1,1};
int buffer2[30]={2,2,2,2,2};
int reason;

pid=fork();
if(pid==-1)
    exit(200);
else if(pid==0)
{
    waitpid(pid_child,&reason,WIFEXITED(reason));
    fprintf(stderr,"exited with %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(reason));
    affiche(buffer1);
    exit(77);
}
pid2=fork();
if(pid2==-1)
    exit(200);
else if(pid2==0)
{
    pid_child=getpid();
    affiche(buffer2);
    exit(2);
}

}
```

**Output**

```
exited with 0
1-1-1-1-1
2-2-2-2-2
```

**Questions**

So **first** the 0 exit code ? how come ?
**Second** , I was expecting having 2's before 1's ?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. [man waitpid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid). What do you intend to pass to the third `waitpid` argument? What do you think is the value of `pid_child` when `waitpid` is executed? `I was expecting having 2's before 1's` - why? If they are separate processes, so should be executing _at the same time_, why would you expect that one will happen after/before another?

Comment: Thanks for answering , I tried to use waitpid in order to make the first child wait for the second one to finish !

Comment: But they are not each other childs. They are not connected.

Comment: Okeey I see . And so how can I do it ?

Comment: You can't wait on others childs. Parent can wait on one child and send the exit status to the second child, if you really need to.

Comment: yes I know but the  main problem is how can I get 2's before 1's

Comment: In question you are asking "I want the second one to wait for the first one", but in comments you want 2's before 1's and in your code it seems first child waits for something to run.

Comment: @unlut edited ..

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution is let the main parent process control both children, and send them necessary signals whenever needed. But if you want children to signal each other directly, you can use semaphores to achieve what you want. I will show example code, but would like to mention a few points first:
1- You don't need to specify a size for buffer1 and buffer2 as compiler can figure it out from right hand side.
2- Its better if your affiche function takes number of elements in array as a second parameter, but I am leaving it for now.
3- Like malloc and free (actually more like fopen and fclose), a semaphore allocated with sem_get should be cleaned up `with semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);`, since I am not sure how your code structure will look like, I am just mentioning it here. You should do it where its appropriate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>




#define SEM_KEY 8  //  an arbitrary number
int sem_id;



//  val may be positive or negative
void add_semaphore_value(int semid, int val)
{
    struct sembuf semaphore;
    semaphore.sem_num = 0;
    semaphore.sem_op = val;
    semaphore.sem_flg = 0;   
    semop(semid, &semaphore, 1);
}


void affiche(int *tab)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%i-%i-%i-%i-%i\n",tab[0],tab[1],tab[2],tab[3],tab[4]);
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid,pid2;

    pid_t child_1_pid;
    pid_t child_2_pid;

    int buffer1[]={1,1,1,1,1};
    int buffer2[]={2,2,2,2,2};

    int f;

    //  initialize semaphore
    sem_id = semget(SEM_KEY, 1, 0700|IPC_CREAT);

    //  set semaphore's value to 0
    semctl(sem_id, 0, SETVAL, 0);

    pid=fork();
    if(pid==-1)
        exit(200);
    else if(pid==0)
    {
        //  first child here
        //  make first child wait until second child increase semaphore
        //  wait until semaphore value >= 1
        add_semaphore_value(sem_id, -1);

        affiche(buffer1);
        exit(77);
    }
    child_1_pid = pid;

    pid2=fork();
    if(pid2==-1)
        exit(200);
    else if(pid2==0)
    {
        //  second child here
        affiche(buffer2);

        //increase semaphore value so first child can continue
        add_semaphore_value(sem_id, 1);

        exit(2);
    }
    child_2_pid = pid2;
}
```

Comment: 1- This does not correspond to his request. 2- Your execution scenario does not even require the use of semaphore, a `waitpid` is largely sufficient where you do `add_semaphore_value (sem_id, -1);`

Comment: @Landstalker Second child waits for first one to finish (not exact finish moment technically), how this does not correspond to request?

Comment: See his code.  `waitpid(pid_child,&reason,WIFEXITED(reason));` is in the first child.

Comment: But his question says "My problem is I have two childs and I want the second one to wait for the first one" , not the other way around.

Comment: its problem is precisely this, he cannot make a `waitpid` because he does not have the PID of the target process because it has not yet been created. But in your code, we can replace `add_semaphore_value (sem_id, -1);` by a `waitpid` because we have the target PID. Your case is solvable without using the semaphore

Comment: I never said it can't be solved without semaphore, I just asked why you think this does not correspond to request.

Comment: See his last comment : *yes I know but the main problem is how can I get 2's before 1's* *

Comment: How you can synchronise two process with `waitpid` if you don't have the cible PID ?! (first argument of `waitpid`).  I think it's a bit complicated ...

Comment: When i read your code, i see that that the first child do a *release*, but in his code, the first child *wait* !

Comment: @Landstalker I just read the question (which asks how to make second child wait for first one) and answered accordingly, but you are right about his code in the question and comment, I think it seems you are right, he wants the other way around. I think wording of the question is not good.

Comment: @Landstalker I will just delete this answer and asked OP about the question in the comments, if I am wrong please correct me there, thanks.